# Ruby shell : how to stop a REPL copy-paste from executing?

Tags: ruby, user-controls

I have some quite long script that I want users to slightly adapt to their scenario before they can copy paste in in some IRB or pry shell.

Most people would, unless paying attention, blindly copy-paste the script in some console. I'd like to stop parsing/executing the rest of the code and (for example) require a user to explicitely validate that he wants to continue running the script (for example via a simple gets that force the user to type `enter`)

I was thinking of something like (imagine this is the code of a wiki that one would copy paste)

```
# Start script
[...] # Some stuff
# Copy paste the autorization code you receive from the internet in the `token` variable
string = ("Do not blindly copy-paste, Did you do what was written in the command just above ? We need the token in the `token` variable. If you did it, just press enter. Otherwise abort with CTRL+C and restart the script".purple)
puts string
gets
Service.call(token)
```

The problem is that the gets/coloration seems to break further execution of the copy pasted script.

My question is, assuming you have a chunk of code that you copy paste using REPL, is there a way to abort/pause the automatic Read-Evaluate print loop via some code contained in the chunk that is copied ?

Basically I'm writing some test procedure that testers can just copy paste in their terminal to check a feature is working. 99% of the time, is is enough to just set some variables and copy-paste the code provided in the examples. But sometimes, there are some (optional) manual steps to be done in the middle of the execution of the code that is copy pasted (like copying a token, retrieving the automatically generated ID, etc.)

Comment: wrap everything in a method/class/lambda

Comment: Erm... Rather than asking users to copy+paste a chunk of code, and modify some parts of it (e.g. a `token`), why not make this a method/rake task/whatever and add a required parameter(s) (or `ENV` variable)? Copy-pasting code directly into the terminal is not a good user experience!

Comment: The particular use case here, is a documentation with almost-ready-to-copy-paste code examples that explains how to use a given service from the console (so the documentation and the examples to copy-paste are already very high level).
We need flexibility, not hardcoded code, and often those scripts are scripts you'll run once of twice in the life of the whole application.